# How do I return content along with an HTTP 300 response in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, http-status-codes

I'd like to have an action in my ASP.NET MVC (not Core) application that returns an HTTP response with a status code of 300 and some text/html content.

```
Response.StatusCode = 300;
Response.RedirectLocation = url;
return View();
```

However, it seems like setting the status code to 300 causes the response to not get written. Is there some way I can accomplish this?

It doesn't matter to me whether a Location header is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - it looks like the response does get written. I was using Firefox to test, and Firefox will ignore the body when it gets the Location header, so it isn't visible in the devtools.